# How to pass integer value between forms without text boxes

Tags: vb.net

I have a Main form that has a button. When pressed I want the integer value for i to = 0. I then want to pass this value of 0 to form2. Form2 counts i + 1 every minute for a sub on form2 but I want it to reset every time the button on the main form is pressed. I know how to pass string values from comboboxes, textbox ect. but I need to pass a variable that is not displayed like other questions on here have asked.

So basically everytime the button is pushed on the main form the i value on form2 will equal 0.

Comment: That is what I am doing now but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way. I have to do this 4 times, for 4 different counting events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have put your variable at class level you just have to make it `Public` or `Friend` to be able to access it from other forms/classes/etc.

**Form2:**

```
Public Class Form2
    Public i As Integer = 0
    ...
End Class
```

**Your button in Form1:**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.i = 0
End Sub
```

Read more about access levels on the [**MSDN Documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. I knew it was something simple. Unfortunately i cant upvote your answer.

Comment: @holi4683 : That's alright, marking as answer if it solved your problem is fine. I'm glad I could help!